# Symfony: array for choice_attr not displaying for radio buttons

Tags: forms, symfony

I've been trying to add HTML attributes to my radio buttons, but somehow it doesn't work. I'm using the built-in `choice_attr` option. In this case I do not want to use a callable, as the definition of `choice_attr` says that the value can be a callable, string or array. I'd like to use an array. Below is the code, what am I doing wrong?

```
    ->add('plan', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Basic' => 0,
            'Superb (+ €9)' => 1,
            'Super (+ €18)' => 2,
            'Rrah' => 3
        ),
        'expanded' => true,
        'data' => 0,
        'choice_attr' => [
            1 => ['data-price' => '0'],
            2 => ['data-price' => '9'],
            3 => ['data-price' => '18'],
            4 => ['data-price' => '0']
        ])
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choice_attr is used for **HTML attributes** bluppfisk.
See the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr

The parameters of the choice_attr function needs to be one of $val, $key, $index, which represents the value, key and index of the 'choices' array that you use. So you could try:

```
'choice_attr' => function($val) {
    $price = 0;
    if ($val == 1) {
        $price = 9;
    }
    elseif ($val == 2) {
        $price = 18;
    }
    return ['data-price' => $price];
}
```

Comment: but data-* _is_ a valid html attribute. It works in another case, where I use a callable to assign data-out-of-stock attributes. But in this case, where a callable is unnecessary, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So this works, but why won't a normal array work. Because it doesn't really make sense to write code that needs to be processed if you can simply pass on some data.

'choice_attr' => function($plan) {
                    $price = 0;
                    if ($plan == 1) { $price = 9; } elseif ($plan == 2) { $price = 18; }
                    return ['data-price' => $price];
                })

Comment: Hi Alvin, thanks. However, this is what I've already done in my above comment. The documentation says the `choice_attr` value can be an array, callable or string. So why does my array in the original example not work?

Comment: **NO**, the documentation clearly says for an array of attributes:"if they are the same for each choice". Also your above example, shows a variable `$plan`, which is not how the function works... You should be using `$val`, which is value. Make sure you read the documentation again - it takes a while to understand it.

Comment: good point, I somehow missed that part despite it only taking up two sentences. If you remove the first part of your answer, I can mark it as valid.

Comment: Edited bluppfisk!